# Access issue of an application running on tomcat

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, tomcat

I have installed an application in a separate asset(server) and hosted it through Apache Tomcat.
The link to access the application http://hostname:portname/appfolderdirectory can be accessed from the browser of the server but not from my computer.
When I connect to that server using remote desktop connection and access that link in it's browser I can access it. But not from my browser.
Let me know if there are any settings need to be changed to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `server.xml` config file in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf` and see whether the Connector binds to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) or whether it binds to 0.0.0.0 or the LAN connection IP or some other non-loopback IP address.

One of mine looks like this:

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" address="172.16.254.2"/>
```

Then restart tomcat, and you should be able to access it across the network